# Trigger invokes the called function multiple time when fired from layout view in marionitte

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am using marionitte framework and i am trying to fire a trigger from one layout view to any other view but its function on the other view is invoked multiple times even though the trigger is fired only once.

Does anyone has got encountered the same issue and has resolved it please let me know the resolution so that i can use in my code.

```
w.src.SourceTabView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template: "#src-template-source-tab-view",

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

regions: {
    "change results"      : "#src-template-change-results-region",
    "change pagination"   : "#src-template-change-pagination-region",
    "document layout"     : "#src-template-document-layout-region",
    "workflow detail"     : "#src-template-workflow-detail-region",
    "job log"             : "#src-template-job-log-region",
    "source job"          : "#src-template-job-region"
},

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

changeInfo: null,

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

mostRecentChange: null,

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

screenCapture: null,

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

regionSelector: null,

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

tab: "details",

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

controls: {
    institution: new w.EntitySelector(null,[]),
    contentSetGroup: new w.EntitySelector(null,["cs"]),
    pageTypes: new w.EntitySelector(null,["page_type"]),
    prevTypes: new w.EntitySelector(null,["previous_type"])
},

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo( this.model , 'sync' , this.render );
    var instTypes = [] ;
    for( var instTypeEntityId in w.INST_TYPES ){
        instTypes.push(instTypeEntityId);
    }
    this.controls.institution = new w.EntitySelector(null,instTypes);
    this.controls.institution.minValueLength = 1;
    this.controls.contentSetGroup.maxValueLength = 1;
    this.controls.contentSetGroup.minValueLength = 1;
    this.controls.prevTypes.minValueLength = 1;
    this.controls.prevTypes.maxValueLength = 1;
    this.fetchMostRecentChange();
    this.regionSelector = null;
    this.changeInfo = new w.src.ChangeInfo(this.model);
    this.changeInfo.vent.on("change-selected", this.render);
    this.changeInfo.vent.on("change-refreshed", this.render);
    this.changeInfo.vent.on("workflow-selected", this.render);
    this.changeInfo.vent.on("workflow-refreshed", this.render);
    this.changeInfo.vent.on("jobLog-view", this.render);
    this.changeInfo.vent.on("workflow-created", w.refreshWorkflows);
    this.changeInfo.vent.on('save-source', this.fromJobRun, this);
},

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

fetchMostRecentChange: function(){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/source/" + self.model.id + "/most-recent-change",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(mostRecentChange){
            if( mostRecentChange ){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/document?change=" + mostRecentChange.id + "&rendering=screen-capture",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response){
                        self.mostRecentChange = mostRecentChange;
                        if( response.results.length > 0 ){
                            self.screenCapture = response.results[0];
                        }
                        self.render.call(self);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
},

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

serializeData: function(){
    var verificationDate = this.model.get('verificationDate');

    // Converting timestamp into readable format
    if(!verificationDate) {
        verificationDate = '';
    } else {
        verificationDate = moment(verificationDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    }
    return {
        model: this.model,
        tab: this.tab,
        minimumChangeInterval: this.humanizeDate(this.model.get("minimumChangeIntervalMs")),
        verificationDate: verificationDate
    }
},

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

onRender: function(){

    var tabRegion = localStorage.getItem("tabRegion"),
        rememberTabs = localStorage.getItem("rememberTabs");
    if( tabRegion && rememberTabs === "true"){
        this.tab = tabRegion;
    } else if( this.tab == null ) {
        this.tab = "details";
    }
    localStorage.setItem("tabRegion", this.tab);

    // content set group
    var contentSetIds = [];
    for( var contentSetId in w.CS ){
        if( this.model.get("entityIds").indexOf(contentSetId) >= 0 ){
            contentSetIds.push(contentSetId);
        }
    }
    this.controls.contentSetGroup.values = contentSetIds;
    this.controls.contentSetGroup.bind(this.$("#src-tab-details-group"));

    // page types
    var pageTypeIds = [];
    for( var pageTypeId in w.PAGE_TYPES ){
        if( this.model.get("entityIds").indexOf(pageTypeId) >= 0 ){
            pageTypeIds.push(pageTypeId);
        }
    }
    this.controls.pageTypes.values = pageTypeIds;
    this.controls.pageTypes.bind(this.$("#src-tab-details-page"));

    // prev types
    var prevTypeIds=[];
    for(var prevTypeId in w.PREV_TYPES){
        if(this.model.get("entityIds").indexOf(prevTypeId)>=0){
            prevTypeIds.push(prevTypeId);
        }
    }
    this.controls.prevTypes.values = prevTypeIds;
    this.controls.prevTypes.bind(this.$("#src-tab-details-previousType"));


    // changes
    var changePaginationView = new w.PaginationView({collection:this.changeInfo.changes});
    changePaginationView.autoHide = true;
    this["change results"].show(new w.src.ChangeCollectionView({collection:this.changeInfo.changes, changeInfo:this.changeInfo}));
    this["change pagination"].show(changePaginationView);

    // institution
    var institutionIds = [];
    _.each(this.model.get("entityIds"),function(entityId){
        if( !w.INST_TYPES[entityId] && !w.PAGE_TYPES[entityId] && !w.CS[entityId] && !w.PREV_TYPES[entityId]){
            institutionIds.push(entityId);
        }
    });
    this.controls.institution.values = institutionIds;
    this.controls.institution.bind(this.$("#src-tab-details-institution"));

    // job
    this["source job"].show(new w.src.SourceJobView({changeInfo:this.changeInfo}));

    // documents
    if( this.changeInfo.selectedChange ){
        var documentLayoutView = new w.src.DocumentLayoutView({collection:this.changeInfo.documents, changeInfo:this.changeInfo});
        this["document layout"].show(documentLayoutView);
        var documentPaginationView = new w.PaginationView({collection:this.changeInfo.documents});
        documentPaginationView.autoHide = true;
        documentLayoutView["document results"].show(new w.src.DocumentCollectionView({collection:this.changeInfo.documents, changeInfo:this.changeInfo}));
        documentLayoutView["document pagination"].show(documentPaginationView);
    } else {
        this["document layout"].close();
    }

    //view job logs
    if(this.changeInfo.viewDetails) {
        var self = this;
        var jobId = this.changeInfo.selectedChange.get('jobId');
        var selectedJobModel = new w.Job({id: jobId});
        selectedJobModel.fetch({ success: function(model) {
            self["job log"].show(new w.src.JobLogView({logger: model.get('logger')}));
        }});
    }

    // workflow detail
    this["workflow detail"].show(new w.src.WorkflowDetailView({changeInfo:this.changeInfo}));

    // other setup
    this.onUrlType();
    this.setTab();
    if(!this.model.isNew()) {
        this.validate();
    }

    if(this.model.get("includedRegions").length) {
        this.$(".delete-all-selected-region").removeClass("disabled");
    }

    // Adding datepicker
    this.$("#verificationDate").datepicker({
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true
    });

},
fromJobRun: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.onUseMyAccountClick();
    this.populateDateToModel();

    // save the model
    this.model.save().success(function() {
        self.onSuccess();
    self.changeInfo.vent.trigger("job-selected");
    }).error(function(response) {
        self.onError(response)
    });
},
});
```

sourceJobView.js

```
w.src.SourceJobView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template: "#src-template-source-job-view",

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

initialize: function(){
    this.options.changeInfo.vent.on("job-selected", this.runJob );


},

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

onRender : function(){
// decide whether to show the job details  link
    if( w.IS_ADMIN ){
        this.$(".jobDetailsMessage").show();
    } else {
            this.$(".jobDetailsMessage").hide();
    }
} ,

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

serializeData: function(){
    return this.options.changeInfo;
},

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
runJob: function() {
    console.log('here');
},

onRunJobClick: function() {
    this.options.changeInfo.vent.trigger("save-source");
}
});
```

According to the code here
Onrunjobclick in sourceJobview triggered is fired to sourceTabview which is listened by fromrunJob which on success fires a trigger back to sourceJobview which is listened by runJob which is invoked multiple times

Comment: Can you post some sample code, or a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this issue is [zombie views](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) - they have been removed from the DOM, but their event handlers remain bound.

You should use `listenTo` instead of `on` to bind events. This allows Marionette's `View.close` method to [clean up old event handlers](https://backbonemarionette.readthedocs.org/en/latest/marionette.view.html#itemview-close) when views are closed.

It's a simple fix:

```
initialize: function(){
  this.listenTo(options.changeInfo.vent, "job-selected", this.runJob);
},
```